# How to Read PDF in Android?

Tags: android, pdf, sd-card

How to Read PDF in Android stored in SDCard ??

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code showing how to open a pdf file to read:

```
private void openBook() {
     File file = new File(mRealPath);
     Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     intent.setDataAndType(path, getString(R.string.application_type));
     try {
         startActivity(intent);
     } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
         Toast.makeText(FirstTab.this, 
         getString(R.string.no_application_found), 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
}
```